# "The constructor ExtentReports(String, boolean) is undefined"

Tags: java, selenium

I am getting "The constructor ExtentReports(String, boolean) is undefined" message while creating object of extentreport class.

```
public  ExtentReports reports;
public ExtentTest test;

@BeforeTest
public void setExtend() {
        reports = new ExtentReports(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/test-output/reports.html",true);   
}
```

Comment: Please tell us what this `ExtentReports` class is, where you are getting it from and which version you are using.  The obvious explanation is that the constructor does not exist ... like the compiler error says.  That implies either your code is wrong ... or the constructor was added or removed in another version and you are using the wrong version.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what API `ExtentReports` belongs to, but if is this one:

https://www.extentreports.com/docs/javadoc/com/aventstack/extentreports/ExtentReports.html

It does not indeed include the constructor `ExtentReport(String,boolean)` you're using, it only has a [parameterless constructor](https://www.extentreports.com/docs/javadoc/com/aventstack/extentreports/ExtentReports.html#ExtentReports--).

Answer (score 0):

Update the Extent Report latest version.
And please read the documentation care fully they explained very good way.
Go through the documentation https://www.extentreports.com/docs/javadoc/com/aventstack/extentreports/ExtentReports.html